# How do I get an image to show after clicking a button in Flask?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, flask

I am trying to make a simple web application using Flask where two documents are selected and then a function is performed (the `dif()` function which calculates the lexical differences and results in an image) and then the image would be shown to the user.

I was able to get the image to show if two documents were hard-coded into the function, but not with a user's file selection. I know my `upload.html` file is incomplete, but I am unsure what needs to be deleted/added/changed.

**routes.py**

```
import io
from app import app 
from app.forms import LoginForm
from pdf_diff.document_differences import dif
from flask import request
from flask import send_file


#converts PIL image into a JPEG
def serve_pil_image(pil_img):
    img_io = io.BytesIO()
    pil_img.save(img_io, 'JPEG')
    img_io.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')

#shows the image from the dif function, using serve_pil_image
@app.route('/test')
def serve_img():
    file1 = "path/to/pdf1"
    file2 = "path/to/pdf2"
    result = dif(file1, file2)
    item = serve_pil_image(result)
    return item

#trying to make user input work 
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET","POST"])
def uploading():
    item = ''
    if request.method =="POST":
        file1 = request.form['file1']
        file2 = request.form['file2']
        if request.form['differences']:
            result = dif(file1, file2)
            item = serve_pil_image(result)
            return item
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

---

**upload.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Choose the first file: <input type="file" name="file1" value="file one"/><BR>
            Choose the first file: <input type="file" name="file2" value="file two"/><BR>
            <input type="button" name="differences" value="Find Differences">
            <input type="submit" name="similarity" value="Similarity Score (Percentage)">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**document_differences.py**

```
import difflib
import io
from tika import parser
import imgkit
import docxpy
from PIL import Image

#function which finds lexical differences between two documents after converting them into text files
def dif(filea, fileb):
if filea.endswith('.pdf'):
    texta = pdf_to_text(filea)
if fileb.endswith('.pdf'):
    textb = pdf_to_text(fileb)
difference = difflib.HtmlDiff().make_file(texta, textb)
difference_report = open('diff_table.html', 'w')
difference_report.write(difference)
difference_report.close()
image = imgkit.from_file('diff_table.html', False)
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
return im
```

Nothing happens when I click the *Find Differences* button, but I'm pretty sure it's because my HTML file is wrong. Any guidance on how to properly format it to coincide correctly with the Python script would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Where is `dif()` defined please? How does your code run without `import` statements?

Comment: I have added all the import statements I have in routes.py and the code for the dif() function. Sorry for not putting it in before!

Answer (score 0):

See, 1st thing you need to understand that you are going to hit the api route with some http methods (***GET***,***POST***, ...)

So your form tag should hit the api using the action attribute.

like `action = /upload`